# Azure Data Explorer partitioning strategy

Tags: aggregate, partitioning, azure-data-explorer, cardinality

I have a table in Azure Data Explorer that collects data from IoT sensors. In the near future it will collect millions of records each day. So to get the best query performance I am looking into setting a partitioning policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy

My table has 5 important columns: TenantId, DeviceId, SensorId, Value, Timestamp

The combination of (TenantId, DeviceId, VariableId) makes a sensor globally unique, and almost all queries will contain a part that says TenantId = 'xx' and DeviceId = 'xx' and VariableId = 'xx'. All these columns are of type string, and have a high-cardinality (10.000+ Tenants, 1000+ DeviceIds, 10.000+ VariableIds)

Two questions:

1. Would it be wise to apply partitioning on this table based on one or more of the string columns? It complies with the advice in the documentation that says:

   - The majority of queries use equality filters (==, in()).
   - The majority of queries aggregate/join on a specific string-typed column of large-dimension (cardinality of 10M or higher) such as an application_ID, a tenant_ID, or a user_ID.

But later on the page, for the MaxPartitionCount they say that it should be not higher than 1024 and lower than the cardinality of the column. As I have high-cardinality columns this does not comply, so I am a bit confused.

2. Would it be best to concat the string columns before ingestion and partition on the new column? Or only on TenantId for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

> almost all queries will contain a part that says TenantId = 'xx' and DeviceId = 'xx' and VariableId = 'xx'.

Given this (and assuming you don't frequently `join` on any of these 3 columns), you could extend your data set with a new column, which is the concatenation of these 3 (e.g. `strcat_delim("_", TenantId, DevideId, VariableId`).

You can do this either before ingestion into Kusto (better), or - using an `update policy` at ingestion time.

Then, set that new column as the `hash partition key` in the table's `data partitioning policy`.

---

2. 

> for the MaxPartitionCount they say that it should be not higher than 1024 and lower than the cardinality of the column. As I have high-cardinality columns this does not comply, so I am a bit confused.

Let's assume you have a cluster with `20` nodes, a column `C` with cardinality `10,000,000`, and you want to set it as the table's `hash partition key`.

Following the guidelines in the documentation regarding `MaxPartitionCount`:

- *Supported values are in the range `(1,1024]`*. -> `MaxPartitionCount` should be larger than `1` and lower than or equal to `1024`.
- *The value is expected to be larger than the number of nodes in the cluster* -> `MaxPartitionCount` should be larger than `20`.
- *The value is expected to be smaller than the cardinality of the column* -> `MaxPartitionCount` should be lower than `10,000,000`.
- *We recommend that you start with a value of `256`.
  Adjust the value as needed, based on the above considerations, or based on the benefit in query performance vs. the overhead of partitioning the data post-ingestion.*

As I don't see any conflicting information here (`256` > `1`, `256` <= `1024`, `256` > `20`, `256` < `10M`) - you may want to clarify where the confusion is coming from.