# Azure Data Explorer partitioning policy

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-data-explorer, cardinality

The documentation on ADX partitioning policy(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy#the-data-partitioning-process) mentions that you need to set a `MaxPartitionCount` while using a hash partition key. It also states that this value should be in the range `(1,2048]` and recommends starting with `128`.

Question: If I have a column with a cardinality of 100,000. Shouldn't the max-partition count be 100,000? Shouldn't ADX create a partition for each distinct value in the column? Why is it even required to fill out this property `MaxPartitionCount`?

Comment: Linking to question quite similar.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489669/azure-data-explorer-partitioning-strategy/63490151#63490151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recommended scenarios (detailed in the doc you've linked to) - The end goal isn't to have a separate partition for each distinct value of the partition key.

- Having an extreme number of partitions (100k in your question, or billions in case of a unique device ID) may result with an extreme amount of small data shards, which would be sub-optimal.
- Even with "only" 128 as the max partition count, alongside default built-in indexing (regardless of explicit data partitioning) - the ability to narrow the full data set down very significantly at query planning time to a small number of partitions/shards can result with significant reduction in resources utilization and execution time.

For further reading: [kusto.blog](https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/data-partitioning.html).

Generally, not following the guidelines and recommendations in the documentation isn't likely to lead you to optimal results.

Comment: Thanks @Yoni. That's more clear which means that each of the distinct values will sit in one of those partitions and help reduce the number of scans.